# Реализация timer countdown

Tags: android, android-sdk

Проблема такая: отсчет у меня в `TextView` стартует с 4-й секунды и по 1-ю, 0 - не показывается, хотя таймер простаивает, как будто считает до нуля. Как мне получить отсчет от 5 к 1.
Может посоветуете другие реализации таймера обратного отсчета?

```
timer = new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                // присваиваю значение TextView
                timerText.setText("00:0" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            }

            public void onFinish() {}
        }.start();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поспешил с вопросом.
Я решил проблему так:
На входе у `CountDownTimer` две переменных:

```
new CountDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {...}
```

Я изменил `long countDownInterval` с 1000 на 1 и все работает, считает от 4 до 0.

Comment: не лучшее решение, вы вызываете onTick каждую мс, может подгрузить поток.

Comment: Хм, что Вы можете посоветовать?

Comment: сейчас отвечу, вам надо, чтоб визуально показывало с 5 к 1 ?

Comment: Да, мне нужно 5 4 3 2 1.

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой способ здесь, немного увеличить время работы таймера, чтоб View элемент успел отобразить.

```
timer = new CountDownTimer(5100, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            // присваиваю значение TextView
            timerText.setText("00:0" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        public void onFinish() {}
    }.start();
```

Отсчет будет с 5 по 1 (визуально) в конце будет небольшая задержка на 100мс, и вызов onFinish().

Comment: Да, я изначально сделал так, но таймер ведет себя непонятно, то начинает отсчет с 4 то с 5.

Comment: Не должно этого быть, поставьте время 5999 тогда 100% будет 5-4-3-2-1 но в конце будет задержка в 999мс. У вас таймер на onCLick привязан? Кстати у Вас "00:0" + millisUntilFinished / 1000 при 10+с и больше будет не красиво

Comment: Мне только с 5 нужно.

Answer (score 0):

```
timer = new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            // присваиваю значение TextView
            timerText.setText("00:0" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            if (millisUntilFinished == 1000) {
                timer.cancel();
            }
        }

        public void onFinish() {}
    }.start();
```

Comment: У меня ничего не изменилось.